# How To Set State Above Pages In Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gatsby

Considering that [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/) creates pages automatically when component files are added to the folder, how do I create a higher-order-stateful-component above the pages so that I can control state for navigation & other common universal components?

Or are we to create the individual state within the page components even if it means repetition?

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a layout component like this? https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10415

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this is what I am currently doing and not happy with. I'd rather have a shared state above the pages rather than repeat the layout as the questioner is doing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`wrapPageElement`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#wrapRootElement) or [`wrapRootElement`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#wrapRootElement) api in `gatsby-browser.js` and `gatsby-ssr.js` to achieve this.

- `wrapPageElement` is meant for persistent UI component, i.e components that shouldn't be unmounted during page change. For example, gatsby's own [layout plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-layout/) use this api to wrap the whole page content inside a user defined Layout component (this used to be the default behavior in gatsby 1).
- `wrapRootElement` is meant for data provider. For example, if you want to [use redux](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-redux) or styled-component theme, you can wrap their Provider component with this api.

`gatsby-browser.js` will only run in the browsers while `gatsby-ssr.js` will run during page generation, so it's likely that you'd want to use both apis at the same time.

Comment: The `wrapPageElement` certainly sounds like what I need. Will implement & get back with feedback &/or any questions. Thanks for the guidance Derek.